# Filter dynamic data table in php

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

I have my first website developed in php which users can display employee bio-metric logs and they can manipulate what department should display in the table by selecting in combo-list and also can be exported through excel. Now i want to filter my data with date range using date 2 time-picker, can someone show me some links or examples that can easily to understand for newbie like me. Below is my Index.php

Index.php

```
    <?php
      $conn =mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bio_db");

      function filterTable($sql)
       {
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","bio_db");
        $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        return $filter_Result;
      }

      $post_at = "";
      $post_at_to_date = "";
      $queryCondition = "";

    if(isset($_POST["search"]["post_at"])) {
    $post_at = $_POST["search"]["post_at"];
    list($fid,$fim,$fiy) = explode("-",$post_at);


    $post_at_to_date = date('Y-m-d');
    if(isset($_POST["search"]["post_at_to_date"])) {
        $post_at_to_date = $_POST["search"]["post_at_to_date"];
        list($tiy,$tim,$tid) = explode("-",$_POST["search"] ["post_at_to_date"]);
        $post_at_to_date = "$tiy-$tim-$tid";
    }

        $queryCondition .= "Where post_at BEETWEEN '$fiy-$fim-$fid' AND '" .$post_at_to_date. "'";
}

     else { $sql = "SELECT * from daily_data2 " .$queryCondition. " ORDER BY post_at ASC";
        $search_result = filterTable($sql);
    }


    ?>



  <html>
   <head>
   <title>Time and Attendance Monitoring</title>        
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

   <style>
    .table-content{border-top:#CCCCCC 4px solid; width:50%;}
    .table-content th {padding:5px 20px; background: #F0F0F0;vertical-align:top;} 
    .table-content td {padding:5px 20px; border-bottom: #F0F0F0 1px     solid;vertical-align:top;} 
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="demo-content">
    <h2 class="title_with_link">Time and Attendance Monitoring</h2>
   <form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="index.php">
    <p class="search_input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="From Date" id="post_at" name="search[post_at]"  value="<?php echo $post_at; ?>" class="input-control" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="To Date" id="post_at_to_date" name="search[post_at_to_date]" style="margin-left:10px"  value="<?php echo $post_at_to_date; ?>" class="input-control"  />             
    <input type="submit" name="go" value="Search" >
    </p>
   <?php if(!empty($result))     { ?>



  <table align="center" width="600" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Userid</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Campaign</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Hoursworked</th>
            <th>Overtime</th>
        </tr>

    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row['Userid'];?></td>
            <td width="200"><?php echo $row['Name'];?></td>
            <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row['Campaign'];?>       </td>
            <td width="100" style="text-align:center;"><?php echo    $row['Date'];?></td>
            <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row['Hoursworked'];?></td>
            <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row['Overtime'];?>   </td>
        </tr>

    <?php endwhile;?>

        </table>
   <?php } ?>
   </form>
   </div>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <script>
   $.datepicker.setDefaults({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "datepicker.png",
    buttonText: "Date Picker",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'  
   });
    $(function() {
    $("#post_at").datepicker();
    $("#post_at_to_date").datepicker();
    });
   </script>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Dear Seryu, Welcome to stackovweflow, please see how to ask question, Also where is your code, what you have tried so far. Giving me links or examples is not stackoverflow is for.

Comment: see edit for my code

Comment: Just a small offtop. Strongly advise to read about SQL injections and https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project.

Comment: If I understand correct you need to use ORDER BY in mysql , http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: Please show us your database table structure

Comment: @VishnuRNair I think he wants to select to timestamps/dates from an date 2 time-picker and use this 2 timestamps/dates to select with a `BETWEEN` condition

Comment: users select date from the 2 datetimepicker (From_, To_) and click filter or whatever button and table filters the data base on the inputted date.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: hi guys can you please check my code what am i missing? i add the 2 date tim picker but upon running my table does not appearing!

Comment: do you gets any error ?

Comment: please see my edits

Answer (score 1):

Still I don't understand your question clearly but I think you are asking about this ,

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM daily_data2 WHERE (DATE BETWEEN 'YOUR-FROM-DATE'  AND 'YOUR-TO-DATE')";
```

give your FROM date and TO date in the query this will get you the data between these two dates as like [DestinatioN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4575671/destination) said

> EDIT

use , `"'$post_at_to_date'"` instead of  `'" .$post_at_to_date. "'` (after 'AND' Condition) because it's just printing the variable name.